# Reward for Passing Review tests?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, review-audits

Just wanted to see what the community thought of adding a reward to passing the review tests? Maybe a **1 point reward**?

I know seeing the tests in the review area has helped me be extra careful when reviewing, but I thought perhaps a little boost in incentive would be cool.

Comment: The reward is to let you continue to do reviews!

Comment: @HugoDozois LOL, fair enough.

Comment: We need less rewards and more punishment.

Comment: "Extra careful?" The tests are *trivial* if you put any effort into the review at all.  I wouldn't want to further incentivize you to spend time on review if you find these challenging.

Comment: Not understanding the downvotes though. Is this not the proper place for discussions like this?

Comment: The problem with a reward is that you can just keep pushing Skip and only do review audits to get the rewards... Not viable.

Comment: @ckpepper02 downvotes mean different on meta - just disagree.

Comment: @djechlin Thanks for the clarity.

Comment: @animuson - that does not sound right to me.... I've never been able to differentiate a real close vote from a audited close vote. Otherwise, I would never fail an audit ;) But I've never tried to figure out how to cheat the system.

Comment: @djechlin - I don't believe some of those tests are trivial.

Comment: @noloader Maybe not in the Close and Reopen queues, but audits in the other four queues are generally *blatantly obvious*, as in if you failed them you *deserve* to be banned because you were clearly *not* paying attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever I pass a review audit, I do notice that my review count still gets incremented.  So passing a review audit *does* get you closer to the Review family badges: Assuming you already have "Custodian" (1 review on a queue), you'll get that much closer to "Reviewer" (250 reviews on a queue) and "Steward" (1000 reviews on a queue).

There is already an incentive for passing review audits -- the badges.  I don't think it's necessary to include a reputation reward for passing review audits.

Comment: I didn't realize that the review count increments during the tests. That should be good enough for sure.